# C++ OpenGL Bitmap transparency issues

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap

I started with opengl texturing and everything was working well. Now I am trying to load a bmp and make white part transparent using glEnable(GL_BLEND);    and glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

This is my source code:

```
float kSpeedForw=0.0f;
GLuint      texture[1];
CCamera g_Camera;                                   
GLfloat     xrot = 0;                              
GLfloat     yrot = 0;                          
GLfloat     zrot = 0;                        
bool  g_bFullScreen = true;                             
HWND  g_hWnd;                                       
RECT  g_rRect;                                          
HDC   g_hDC;                                        
HGLRC g_hRC;                                        
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;                                  
float jump = -0.1;
GLfloat LightAmbient[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
GLfloat LightDiffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat LightPosition[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };
void Init(HWND hWnd)
{
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            // Enable Texture Mapping
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black Background
glClearDepth(1.0f);                                 // Depth Buffer Setup
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, LightAmbient);     // Setup The Ambient Light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);     // Setup The Diffuse Light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);   // Position The Light
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);                                // Enable Light One

glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5);                   // Full Brightness.  50% Alpha
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
g_hWnd = hWnd;                                      
GetClientRect(g_hWnd, &g_rRect);                
InitializeOpenGL(g_rRect.right, g_rRect.bottom);
g_Camera.PositionCamera(0, 1.5f, 6, 0, 1.5f, 5, 0, 1, 0);
ShowCursor(false);                      
}
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename)
{

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GLuint texture;

int width, height;

unsigned char * data;

FILE * file;

file = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (file == NULL) return 0;
if (filename=="Data/weed.bmp"){
    width = 200;
    height = 200;
}
if (filename == "Data/gun.bmp"){
    width = 300;
    height = 300;
}
data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3);
fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
fclose(file);

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
{
    int index = i * 3;
    unsigned char B, R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index + 2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index + 2] = B;

}
if (filename == "Data/weed.bmp"){
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);


    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    free(data);
}
if (filename == "Data/gun.bmp"){
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

}


return texture;
}


WPARAM MainLoop() // main function
{
MSG msg;
Init(g_hWnd);
glClearColor(0, 0, 255, 0);
while (1)                                           
{                                                   
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)                 
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);                 
        DispatchMessage(&msg);                      
    }
    else if (LockFrameRate(60))                 
    {
        g_Camera.SetViewByMouse();                  
        kSpeedForw = 0;
    if (jump > -0.1)jump-=0.01;

        CheckForMovement();                     


        g_Camera.MoveCamera(kSpeedForw, jump);
        RenderScene();                              
    }
    }

DeInit();
return(msg.wParam);                             
}
void RenderScene()
{
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();                                   
gluLookAt(g_Camera.m_vPosition.x, g_Camera.m_vPosition.y, g_Camera.m_vPosition.z,
g_Camera.m_vView.x, g_Camera.m_vView.y, g_Camera.m_vView.z,
g_Camera.m_vUpVector.x, g_Camera.m_vUpVector.y, g_Camera.m_vUpVector.z);


GLuint texture;
texture = LoadTexture("Data/weed.bmp");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                              
float i = 0;
glColor3f(1,1,1);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-10 + i / 5, 0, 10 - i / 5);


glTexCoord2f(50.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-10 + i / 5, 0, -10 + i / 5);


glTexCoord2f(50.0f, 50.0f);
glVertex3f(10 - i / 5, 0, -10 + i / 5);


glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 50.0f);
glVertex3f(10 - i / 5, 0, 10 - i / 5);
glEnd();                            
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////HUD
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);         // Turn Blending On

int vPort[4];

glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vPort);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0, vPort[2], 0, vPort[3], -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

GLuint ruka;
ruka = LoadTexture("Data/gun.bmp");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ruka);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);


glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0, 0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(450,0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(450,450);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0,450);
glEnd();



SwapBuffers(g_hDC);
}
```

The code works well for loading and rendering the platform(weed.bmp) and it also loads and renders gun fine. But big part of gun.bmp is white. I was hoping to get that part transparent. I was also hoping to add more HUD features, which would also need to be partly transparent.

My gun.bmp file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxxlNcAI0eh9cHZGd1ZfMTFwYmM/view?usp=sharing

If you know a solution of this problem please post it. Thanks

Comment: I really wonder how you expect that white _magically_ becomes transparent by enabling `GL_BLEND`.

Comment: I tried loading a 32 bit bmp with alpha channels and loading as GL_RGBA but it immedietely crashed. I don't know whether I am missing something here but if so, please explain to me what. I would be most thankful.

Comment: You should use an actual image loading library for this (or a less confusing file extension). I get the impression that your ".bmp" file here is not actually a *Device Independent Bitmap*. The DIB format has a complicated header you would have to process and you also have to account for 4-byte per-row alignment (not an issue here since 200*3 and 300*3 are both divisible by 4 without a remainder).

Comment: post it as an answer with a image loading library and a format recommendation (I should use png, right) and I would happily accept it as an answer.

Comment: That wasn't really an answer. I still have no idea why it works when you use a 24-bit bmp. Generally though, PNG is probably the most widely supported image format (for editing software and loading libraries) that stores an alpha channel. As for libraries, I would point you [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries). I've seen DevIL, FreeImage and SOIL questions in the last month alone, so you shouldn't have too much trouble finding support.

Answer (score 0):

You load image as GL_RGB, you want GL_RGBA to have an alpha channel.
Also, you need a 32 bits Bitmap (8 bits/channel × 4 channels = 32 bits).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I did try that but it caused immediete crash

Comment: You have to use 32bits bitmaps and read `width * height * 4` bytes.

Comment: Yes, I did use a 32 bit bitmap. It was loaded as GL_RGBA and was saved with alpha channel.